# Error converting 0 to double on user's machine with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, double

I have a Silverlight application that gets down data from the server in the form of an XML string, opens it as a document, and parses through things.

This works on all other machines, but we have client with a user who's machine is unable to run things properly. Her box gives her an InvalidCastException that looks like it's trying to convert 0 to a Double.

This seems like an environmental issue, but I can't figure out what the cause of this would be or how to fix it. Her cultural settings appeared okay, at least for the numeric settings.

Anyone bumped into anything similar or have any next steps for diagnosis or possible fixes? I don't think we can attach to the machine or anything.

Relevant stack trace included below:

```
[InvalidCast_FromStringTo]

Arguments: 0,Double

Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments 
provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.10411.0&File=Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll&Key=InvalidCast_FromStringTo 

Type: System.InvalidCastException

at 
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String 
Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)

at MyNamespace.MyLoader.LoadXml(String xml)
```

Comment: Just a thought: Is your client in a country where they might have a decimal separator of ",", or could they have their localisation settings wrong?

Comment: We've tried reproducing this with different localization settings and using , for decimal spaces but the error doesn't seem to occur and only seems specific on one machine. Generally we're using InvariantCulture when we can.